# How to style autofilled content? (Android O)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-autofill-manager

I would like to know if and how you can style android `auto-filled` content (using the `autofill` service that is new in `Android O`). Right now it highlights `auto-filled` content with yellow and I would like to style it so that `auto-filled` content is no different from normal content.

To be clear, I'm not making my own manager, I just want to change the look of `auto-filled` content in my app.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the highlighting is there to benefit the user, so they see what data was filled in and can verify that they want to provide that data to your app.

Comment: You can customize the autofilled content by overriding the _android:autofilledHighlight_ item from your them, as described here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html#highlighted

(sorry for not documenting that before).

-- Felipe

Comment: I mean, "from your theme". 

Anyways, as Mark mentioned, the field is highlighted so the user knows the content was autofilled, you should not change it to look the same (as if the user filled it).